# extjs: getting many nodes with specific value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have several nodes with the save value (for example, marked for deletion). How can I get all of them? FindChild can give me just the first node, as I can see...
This part is from documentation:

```
findChild( attribute, value, [deep] ) : Ext.data.NodeInterface

Finds the first child that has the attribute with the specified value.
```

I have a treeStore, where one can check some elements for deletion, then click "save" button. After that I want to have all checked elements. And with findChild method I can get just first of them:

```
...store.getRootNode().findChild( 'delete', true, true )
```

What shall I do to get all of them?

Comment: Please explain better. It's difficult to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop over all nodes and find nodes which have `delete` property set to `true` you can use

```js
store.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function(node) {
  if (node.get('delete') === true) {
    ...  
  }
});
```

But if you are using `Ext.tree.Panel` for displaying tree, you can simply add checkboxes and get checked nodes as it is described in Sencha Check tree example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#check-tree